# ¿Cuándo usar “haber” (el perfecto) versus el pretérito?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Todavía no entiendo cuál es la diferencia entre los tiempos pasado perfecto (ex. he cantado) y pretérito indefinitivo (ex. canté). Ambos parecen representar una acción completada en el pasado reciente. A menudo la misma frase se puede expresar correctamente en cualquiera de los dos tiempos. ¿Qué es lo que te hace elegir el pretérito en una situación o el pasado perfecto en la otra?

EDICIÓN: por “haber” estoy refiriendo al tiempo perfecto, ni el pasado imperfecto como dije incorrectamente en la publicación original

Comment: Si hablas inglés es exactamente igual

Comment: @aris inglés es mi lengua materna, cuál es la diferencia cuando hablando español?

Comment: una aclaración, en gramática *tense* se traduce como *tiempo*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Description of past perfect tense](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/description-of-past-perfect-tense).  Also helpful: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23361/9385.

Comment: @walen sí, eso es correcto. Disculpe, editaré la publicación original. ¿Puedes explicar la diferencia entre el pretérito indefinitivo y el perfecto?

Comment: @willow no hay diferencia ninguna. en ingles tienes "have done," "has done," "had done", "did," etc. es igual en español. no hay diferencia ninguna. si entiendes las diferencias de las formas del pasado en ingles, entonces seguramente entiendes como son en el idioma español